# Fullcalendar in Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail class not resizing with other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, resize, fullcalendar, thumbnails

I am attempting to put a weekly agenda in a row of thumbnails using Fullcalendar, but the resizing doesn't seem consistent.

1) On my work monitor, the agenda table renders correctly at full screen width, then changes to being taller than the neighboring thumbnails when the screen is narrowed, and then returns to correct rendering at full width. It also renders correctly when in mobile emulation and the row switches from horizontal to vertical configuration. The screen resolution is 1920x1080.

2) At home, the agenda renders *initially* as taller than the neighboring thumbnails at full width, then remains taller as the horizontal dimension decreases, renders correctly in mobile emulation, then renders correctly when the screen is restored to full-width. Screen resolution is 1366x768.

The base dimensions of the neighboring images are 465x300.

Relevant code bits. The jQuery calling the calendar (in the `$(document).ready()` section).

```
$('#calendar-index').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    height: $("#imgSource").height(),
    width: $("#imgSource").width(),
    windowResize: function(view) {
        this.height() = $("#imgSource").height();
        this.width() = $('#imgSource').width();
    }
});
```

The HTML section:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center"><div id="calendar-index"></div><a href="full_cal.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button Text</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center"><img id="imgSource" src="image1.png"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button Text</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center"><img src="image2.png"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button Text</a></div>
    </div>
```

I've got a feeling that connecting it to a `$("#imgSource").load()` rather than `$(document).ready()` call would work, but I'm avoiding using deprecated functions if possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/sidhenimh/63e0h54o/

Comment: I've tried, also, using the `aspectRatio` built-in of Fullcalendar, but it doesn't work to render the dimensions correctly, either. The line inserted was `aspectRatio = $("#imgSource").width/$("#imgSource").height` - however, as I said, it didn't render at any resolution correctly.

Comment: Could you provide us a fiddle?

Comment: @azeos http://jsfiddle.net/sidhenimh/63e0h54o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this, in case anyone else runs into a similar issue; it doesn't work perfectly, but it does at least make the horizontal scaling a lot more stable. There's a free jQuery plugin called "Datatables" that enables automatic horizontal scaling. Vertical scaling doesn't work still, but the table at least displays correctly initially regardless of monitor resolution/size.

[Datatables Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/)